# Dynamic Tab with Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

total novice,but bit familiar with static tabs addition to view pager.But here I stuck in dynamic tabs which I am able to show but not the fragments of those dynamically received tabs.How would I add fragments to those dynamically received tabs from server.Pardon me spelling and could be ambiguous question

Answer (score 0):

> Follow this link example and change the following method.
>   Visit https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_OF_FRAGMENT;i++){
        adapter.addFragment(new YourFragment(), "Title"+i);
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

You need only one fragment for creating dynamic tab.